# How to customize the heading of the table of content page

Tags: table-of-contents, packages

I am writing in the *book* class, and I want to underline the "CONTENTS" heading on the *table of content* page. However, as soon as I attempted to customize it in the following way -

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents\\%
\vspace{-0.5cm}%
\hfill \rule{0.6\textwidth}{1.2pt}%
}
```

the heading "CONTENTS" with the underline began to appear in the header (top of the page) of the following pages, which I understand is quite natural.
[image: The heading printed as desired]

[image: The rule beneath the heading continued in the header]

Could you please suggest a way that such an underline appears only in the heading and not in the header. I am relatively new to \LaTex and in a phase of understanding how it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton